# HTML file not displaying the Console.log text on the console

Tags: html

I have a html file, where i am trying to print on the console between script tags - "Console.log("Hello"); It doesn't display on my Visual Studio Code console. However, if written in server.js file, does display on the console. Help please.

Comment: I don't work with Visual Studio, but i'd expect the output of a `console.log` to appear in the browser's console, rather than the IDE's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console logs for client-side JavaScript appear in the browser console, not in the server console. You see NodeJS console logs in your IDE because your IDE's terminal is connected to your server. Your IDE's terminal is not connected to your browser's instance of your web application.

You can typically open your browser console by pressing F12 in the tab in which your application is open.

Comment: @Pavani, if his answer helped you don't forget to accept it.